# Return value X where all rows that value fit criteria in other column

Tags: sql

I need to return a list of numbers where *all* rows having the same number fit criteria in another column.

For example, all rows with same "num" must have non-null values in the Check-in column.

```
num| Check-in

 1| null
 1| X
 1| X
 2| X
 2| X
 3| X 
 3| X
```

Desired return: `2, 3`

I know there has to be a simple way to do this without looping! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try grouping with a filter using `having`, here it compares the count of rows in each group with the count of rows per group that are not `null`, you only want those rows where the counts match.

```
select num
from t
group by num
having Count(*)=count(checkin);
```

Comment: `count(checkin) = count(*)` No real need for the case expression with nulls.

Comment: Thanks yes as it's a null/not null this is more succinct.

Comment: Thanks, Group By is the basic thing I was missing!